# python replacement for xml

Tags: python, replace

I have file, FF_tuningConfig_AMPKi.xml, contains of records such as:

```
<KiConfig active="%{active}" id="AMP_RET_W_LIN_SUSPICIOUS_MULTIPLE_LOGIN_IN_SHORT_PERIOD$KiConfig"/>
<KiConfig active="%{active}" id="AMP_RET_W_LIN_UNUSUAL_SESSION_HOUR_OF_DAY$KiConfig"/>
```

I have the following code:

```
def replace_content(path,se,search,String_Replace):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            if((se in filename)):
                file=open(os.path.join(root, filename),'r')
                lines = file.readlines()
                file=open(os.path.join(root, filename),'w')

                for line in lines:
                    if search in line:
                    #print "found="+line
                        words=line.split('=')
                    #    print words
                     #   print "line=" + words[0] +"="+ "8\n" 
                        line=line.replace(line,String_Replace)
                    #print "after="+line
                    file.write(line)
                file.close()
                print (os.path.join(root,filename) + " was replaced")

replace_content(Path,'FF_tuningConfig_AMPKi.xml','<KiConfig active="%{active}"','<KiConfig active="true"')
```

I am getting the below:

```
active="true"      <Thresholds>
```

Instead of:

```
<KiConfig active="true" id="AMP_RET_W_LIN_UNUSUAL_SESSION_HOUR_OF_DAY$KiConfig"/>
```

Comment: `I am getting ...` - what does that mean? Your function doesn't return anything.  Is that what it is printing?

Comment: @wwii Presumably that is what OP is getting in their XML file

Comment: Your problem could be reduced to - open then read a file; replace strings in the resulting content; write the modified content to a file.  Presumably the problem is with modifying the content.  When you ask questions, if you provide us with a [mcve] it helps focus our efforts.  Sometimes when you construct an mcve for us, it helps you find the problem.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a question. What do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `line=line.replace(line,String_Replace)`. Take a look at the documentation for [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
line = line.replace(search,String_Replace)
```

---

To test your code, you could have written a separate *script* with only the part that seemed to be failing.

```
# test input
s = '''<KiConfig active="%{active}" id="AMP_RET_W_LIN_SUSPICIOUS_MULTIPLE_LOGIN_IN_SHORT_PERIOD$KiConfig"/>
<KiConfig active="%{active}" id="AMP_RET_W_LIN_UNUSUAL_SESSION_HOUR_OF_DAY$KiConfig"/>'''

lines = s.split('\n')

# parameters
search, String_Replace = '<KiConfig active="%{active}"','<KiConfig active="true"'

# Then the part of your code that seems to be failing
for line in lines:
    if search in line:
        line = line.replace(line, String_Replace)
    print(line)
```

That lets you focus on the problem and makes it easy and fast to modify then test your code.  Once you have that functionality working, copy and paste it into your working code.  If that part of your code actually works then you have eliminated it as a source for errors and you can test other parts.

---

As an aside, no need to test if your search string is in the line before attempting to replace.  If the search string isn't in the line, `str.replace()` will return the line without modification.